# C++ syntax pointer for array

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, constants

In the following:

```
int c[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};

printArray(c, 10);

template< typename T >
void printArray(const T * const array, int count)
{
    for(int i=0; i< count; i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
}
```

I am a little confused why the function signature of the template function makes no reference to array being an array by using [], so something like `const T * const[] array`.

How could one tell from the template function signature that an array is being passed and not just a non-array variable??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot tell for sure. You would have to read the documentation and/or figure it out from the names of the function parameters. But since you are dealing with fixed sized arrays, you could have coded it like this:

```
#include  <cstddef> // for std::size_t

template< typename T, std::size_t N >
void printArray(const T (&array)[N])
{
    for(std::size_t i=0; i< N; i++)
        cout << array[i] << " ";
}

int main()
{
  int c[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0}; // size is inferred from initializer list
  printArray(c);
}
```

Comment: Is this a better syntax to represent arrays because it's obvious we have an array? Is there any disadvantage to not using a pointer?

Comment: @user997112 The advantages are that you don't have to input the size yourself, since it is figured out by the compiler, and that it is clear that it only works with an array. The only disadvantage is that it doesn't work for dynamically sized arrays.

Comment: The _better_ thing to do is pass a vector, and the _best_ is an arbitrary iterator range.

Comment: @MooingDuck I am assuming it is relevant that the array is fixed size here. I'd say the better thing to do would be to use an `std::array` and overload `std::ostream& operator<<` for it.

Answer (score 5):

An array has a size. To create a reference to an array, you need to provide the size statically. For example:

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
void printArray(T const (&array)[Size]) {
    ...
}
```

This functions takes the array by reference and you can determine its size.

Comment: Is it better to pass arrays by reference because you can refer to the size explicitly?

Comment: Since it instantiates a template for each size I'm only using this for tiny functions like `begin()` and `end()` or in functions immediately delegating to the function doing the actual work. I had a few cases wherebI wanted to wndorce a specific (constant) array size where pass by reference was also handy.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
template< std::size_t N>
struct ArrayType
{
    typedef int IntType[N];
};

ArrayType<10>::IntType content = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0};

template< std::size_t N >
void printArray(const typename ArrayType<N>::IntType & array)
{
    //for from 0 to N with an array
}
void printArray(const int * & array)
{
    //not an array
}
```

Raxvan.